# Reload site at a specific time of day Java/Spring MVC

Tags: java, sql, spring

L:I am using SQL to populate a datatable, but the table is large and I am not able to use PHP. This causes it to load for longer than I'd like. My plan is to have the page auto-update at somepoint in the wee hours of the morning to prevent users experiencing the initial load. I have no idea how to do that. Whether it be a Java or JS function.

Comment: Ever heard for pagination?

Comment: Datatables has pagination by default. 
I want to re-PULL the SQL data at a certain point so the information is up to date.

Comment: Well... shouldn't data be reloaded when users refresh page? Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly then you have a large amount of data in a database which takes a long time query. You've solved this problem by preloading necessary items to your program and you show that to the user. Your problem then is how can you schedule reloading of these items using Spring.

Spring [supports scheduling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) by either using annotations or configuration. Using annotations you may declare for example

```
 @Scheduled(cron="<cron style scheduling rule>")
 public void refresh() {
     // Your implementation
 }
```

Furthermore you must setup enable scheduling before the annotation comes into effect.